# Amcharts - radar chart for one and two data items (amcharts4)

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I am trying to display hexagon or octagon shape like radar series axis in case when I have only one or two items in data. Right Now it renders like that.

[image]

Following is my code snippet. I have looked at adapters for radar chart. So far, nothing useful found.
https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/radarchart/#Adapters

Upon debugging, I found that series.pixelHeight is 0. Can you guys give some pointers. or show me the way?

```
    const chart = am4core.create('al-radial-chart', am4charts.RadarChart)

    chart.logo.disabled = true
    chart.data = data
    chart.radius = am4core.percent(70)

    //* Create axes */
    const categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis())
    const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis())

    // Fields
    categoryAxis.dataFields.category = 'title'
    valueAxis.title.fontWeight = 'bold'
    valueAxis.renderer.gridType = 'polygons'

    // Labels
    valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true
    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = 12
    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = am4core.color(colors.text)

    // Axes
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 2
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.99
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.fillOpacity = 0.05
    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.html = `
    <div style="width: ${
      window.innerWidth < 1000 ? 80 : window.innerWidth < 1500 ? 120 : 150
    }px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; text-align: center;">{category}</div>
    <div style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold">{score.formatNumber("#,###.0")}</div>`
    categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.tooltipText = `[bold]{title}[/]\n score is [bold]{score.formatNumber("#,###.0")}[/]`
    categoryAxis.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false
    categoryAxis.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color(colors.turq)
    categoryAxis.tooltip.background.stroke = am4core.color(colors.turq)

    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.fill = am4core.color(colors.gridFill)
    categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = am4core.color(colors.lines)

    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 2
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.99
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.fillOpacity = 0.05
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.fill = am4core.color(colors.gridFill)
    valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = am4core.color(colors.lines)

    valueAxis.zIndex = 1
    categoryAxis.zIndex = 2

    /* Create and configure series */
    const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.RadarSeries())
    // series.zIndex = 1
    series.dataFields.valueY = 'score'
    series.dataFields.categoryX = 'title'
    series.strokeWidth = 2
    series.stroke = am4core.color(colors.turq)
    series.fillOpacity = 0.4
    series.sequencedInterpolation = true
    series.sequencedInterpolationDelay = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created dummy data with valueAxis values set to zero and with different titles. Have used the categoryAxis `htmlOutput` adapter to hide those labels. Because my values were zero chart rendered correctly. Will post a code solution to this problem shortly.